# Style views row layout debending on result count

Tags: 7, views, theming

How to style views row layout debending on result count?

If views has 4 results then items should be placed on two rows and two columns:
| |
| |

And when views has more than 4 items - for example 6 then: 
| | |
| | |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement [`hook_views_pre_render`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7) and count the number of results, then apply a class to the wrapper element.

```
function hook_views_pre_render(&$view) {
  switch($view->name) {
    case 'MY_VIEW_NAME':
      switch($view->current_display) {
        case 'MY_DISPLAY_ID':

          $numResults = count($view->result);

          /*
            Do your logic with $numResults here
          */
          if ($numResults <= 4) {
            $grid = 2;
          }
          else {
            $grid = 3;
          }

          $view->style_plugin->options['class'] = (isset($view->style_plugin->options['class'])) ? $view->style_plugin->options['class'] . ' grid-' . $grid : 'grid-' . $grid;

          break;
      }
      break;
  }
}
```

So then you can style the width of the views-row under grid-2 to be 50%, and 33% width for views-row under grid-3 in your CSS.

Your View display needs to use "HTML List" format for this code to work.

Comment: Okey. I added to template.php your code and edited:     "function theme_views_pre_render(&$view) {
  switch($view->name) {
    case 'front_tiles-block':
      switch($view->current_display) {
        case 'block':" But it is not adding classes. I have 4 items in front_tiles-block view.

Comment: `front_tiles-block` is not a valid views name. Please check you have correct names in your switch statements. `$view->name` refers to the machine name of your view, it only has numbers, letters and underscores. Dashes are not allowed there.

Comment: Ok, I exported my views and it says: $view->name = 'front_tiles'; - So changed front_tiles-block to front_tiles. But now I'm getting warning: Notice: Undefined index: class in theme_views_pre_render() (line 267 of /home/public_html/sites/all/themes/theme/template.php). And in that 267 line it has code: "$view->style_options['class'] = $view->style_options['class'] . ' grid-'.$grid;"

Comment: Nevermind the warning, are you getting the class name on the wrapper element though?

Comment: Nope. There is no any grid class.

Comment: @hene updated the code, the line just above the first `break`. Tested on my local machine, it works in adding the correct class. Try it out.

Comment: strange, for me it is not adding class. I copied your updated code. Now it does not show warning but it is not adding class. I have cleared cache and tried everything but no luck.

Comment: I tryed this with another drupal installation and same thing there - does not add any class to view. In your drupal where it adds class? To class part in here? <div id="block-views-list-block" class="block block-views"> - What did you use as view display name?

Comment: Your view display name is under "Other" on bottom right corner, labelled "Machine name" in your views edit screen. The class is added to the parent element of views-row. For me it added it to the `<ul>` element as I've used a "HTML List" format for my display.

Comment: Okey, after I changed view formt to HTML list then I see <ul class="grid-2">. But I need it to work on Unformatted list. Any idea how to get it work with Unformatted too?

Comment: Unfortunately there's no option to provide "Wrapper Class" to unformatted list format. Check it yourself by clicking "Settings" next to Unformatted List, and then change it to HTML List and click Settings. HTML List has a field for "Wrapper Class". Why do you specifically need Unformatted list? It's just div -> div instead of ul -> li